# df.columns return the columns with a tuple list not in string list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge 2 df with the same columns name, as always I do `df.columns.to_list()`, but something weird is happening. Instead of getting the list with the strings of the name of the column I'm getting `[('name_column1',), ('name_column2',) ...]` I have been 3 days struggling myself, but even renaming once you do the `.column` still return a tuple.

Thanks very mutch for the help :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the column header get first element in tuple

```py
df.columns = [col[0] for col in df.columns]
# or
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Comment: It tell's me: Too many levels: Index has only 1 levels, not 2

Comment: @Wheel What did you try?

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys, just found it! I was creating the df with columns = [list] instead of columns = list. df_transaccion_4months_not_saved = pd.DataFrame(columns=[columnas])

Answer (score 0):

It is because your dataframe has multi-indexes. Try:

```
col_names = [multi_index[0] for multi_index in df.columns.to_list()]
```